# Why select.setAttribute('value',value) produce different results than select.value=value?

Tags: javascript, dom

*Script 1* will log `two` but the browser will still render the `select` element as **One**. The form will also submit the value `one`. *Script 2* will log, render, and submit `two`. I expect them to be synonyms and do the same thing. Please explain why they differ and where else I should be on the lookout for the same inconsistency.

As I understand it, the `select` element in the DOM doesn’t actually hold the `value` attribute. The first method clearly assigns it and retrieves the value from that element, with no effect on the rendering. How am I supposed to use `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` correctly in the case of a `select` element?

Demo document:

```
<select id="el">
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
</select>
```

Script 1:

```
document.getElementById('el').setAttribute('value','two');
console.log(document.getElementById('el').getAttribute('value'));
```

Script 2:

```
document.getElementById('el').value = 'two';
console.log(document.getElementById('el').value);
```

Comment: Script 2 works fine http://jsbin.com/osexuw/1/edit

Comment: @elclanrs, yes I am aware of that. I want to understand why *Script 1* does not work. I reread my post, and still believe that was clear.

Comment: You already said it - the `value` *attribute* doesn't mean anything for `<select>` elements - it's a different story for `<input />` elements though. When the DOM is parsed, *properties* are created and values taken from the *attributes* (if provided)...and additional *properties* are created. So setting an *attribute* that isn't converted into a property does nothing. But it's still an *attribute* that you can access.

Answer (score 4):

MDN makes no mention of a *value* attribute for [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/select), perhaps you meant the *selected* attribute of [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/option). A *value* attribute would apply to some other form-associated elements, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, etc.

Still, the same applies to the *selected* attribute as with the *value* attribute for those other elements; it won't change the current value, but only the default/initial value of the `<select>`. You can always `.reset` the parent `<form>` to make it applied (this will also reset all other form-associated elements, though). For example;

```
<!-- HTML -->
<form id="f">
    <select id="el">
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Now use *JavaScript* to set a *selected* attribute on an `<option>`, then `reset` the `<form>`;

```
document.getElementById('el').options[1].setAttribute('selected','selected');
document.getElementById('f').reset(); // make it get applied by resetting form
```

[**Demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g6xkp/)

The [*HTMLSelectElement* DOM interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement) does have a property *value*, and this is defined as

> The value of this form control, that is, of the first selected option.

Therefore, setting it (to `x`) loops through the available options looking for the first option with a *value* matching `x`, and (if found) chooses that as the "first selected option", changing the current selection.

Comment: "only the default/initial value of the <select>" - the `value` attribute means nothing, so it won't "set" anything. It just sets a `value` *attribute*, which isn't related to or used for the *property*.

Comment: @Ian I'm not talking about _value_ as an Attribute in terms of `<select>`

Comment: Crap! Sorry, misread :( I'm starting to confuse myself with seeing "attribute" and "property" and "selected" a million times...

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between an attribute and a property.

When the element is initially parsed, the attributes are populated from the values in the HTML code. Those values are then copied to the properties with the corresponding names. So, the attribute contains the initial value, and the property contains the current value.

If you change the attribute, you change what the element think was the initial value, but that doesn't change what the current value is.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `value` attribute defines the *initial* value of the element, while the `value` *property* is the actual value.

After the element is created, there's no point in setting the `value` *attribute*, since it does pretty much nothing.

Comment: The `value` *attribute* means nothing with `<select>` elements. You're right, when referring to `<input />` elements though.