# Getting id of an image in a modal and insert it into a hidden input

Tags: javascript

I have a modal that contains some images, now I want to write a javascript code to get the id of the image that gets clicked and put it in the `value` attribute of a hidden input behind this modal. This code:

```
function getCourseImageId(e){
    var id = e.getAttribute('id');
    // window.alert(id);
    document.getElementById("chosenCoursePicture").setAttribute("value", id);
}
```

Works when I alert the `id`, but not when I use `setAttribute`.

Comment: See here the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369402/why-select-setattributevalue-value-produce-different-results-than-select-val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet below is working if you want a case specific to your you need to provide html part of the code as well.
Basically what i am doing is getting the img tag id with get Attribute and setting the attribute of span element with js.

```js
var id = document.querySelector("img").getAttribute('id');
window.alert(id);    
document.querySelector("span").setAttribute("value", id);
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="place" alt="Placeholder">
<span></span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I found out what the problem was. Unfortunately my code was correct! but I was using chrome "View Page Source" and I've realized that it doesn't get dynamically updated, so I used chrome Inspect->element instead and it shows that the value attribute of the input field being filled properly! :( Bitter experience... :D

Comment: No worries mate!